# How to remove space being printed in else statement

Tags: python

I have this code which returns days, hours, minutes, and seconds from a input.
The issue is, when there is 0 of some value it should print nothing. I put in the else statement to do "", however it still occupies a space in the output which I do not want.

Comment: could you please format your code as to normal python syntax :)

Comment: Maybe you should consider using more than one line of code. Pls provide at least one example of how your output looks like and what you desire instead.

Comment: Not including any code in your question at all is *worse* than what it was before.

Comment: ...that said, using commas is a very big part of your problem: `print 'foo', '', 'bar'` does not print `foobar`, whereas `print 'foo' + '' + 'bar'` *does*. That may be enough of a hint.

Answer (score 1):

```
daystr = ""
hourstr = ""
minutestr = ""
secondstr = ""
if int(days): # 0 equals False
    daystr += days+" days"
if int(hours):
    hourstr += hours+" hours"
if int(minutes):
    minutestr += minutes+" minutes"
if int(seconds):
    secondstr += seconds+" seconds"
outa = ", ".join([i for i in [daystr,hourstr,minutestr,secondstr] if i])
print(outa)
```

like that?? that wont print it if it is zero.

Comment: i have now changed it to your request that time values that equals to 0 should not be printed

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of finding out what was wrong with your code *functionality-wise*:

```
print("a", "b")  # "a b"
```

I assume you use Python 3. Use the `sep` keyword argument to remove the space:

```
print("a", "b", sep="")  # "ab"
```